# Can visual studio or Visual Assist be set to automatically complete parentheses for macros?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, autocomplete

For stl functions, such as `accumulate`, when I enter `accu`, and then press tab in the pop-up candidate list, the left bracket will be automatically generated and the cursor will be placed in the middle of the bracket, as shown in Figure 1
[image]
[image]
I know [visual studio or Visual Assist can do this automatically](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W170)

my question is，Is there a setting to perform such completion for macro commands as well?
For example, for the following macro, when I press D, D() can be automatically completed, and the cursor is placed in the middle of the brackets

> #define D(x) cout << #x << " : " << x << endl;

Comment: macros aren't really code, they are text replacement commands.  If you have to use a macro, you should be able to wrap the macro in a function

Comment: I thought about this, but x could be an arbitrary type of value, maybe I could write tons of overloaded functions to achieve the same thing, but it would cause extra problems, so I don't want to do that @NathanOliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable member list commit aggressive in Tools->Options ->Text editor-> C++ ->Advanced, then you can use shift+9 `(` instead of `tab` to complete parentheses  and place the cursor in the middle. Not all functions, macros need to add parentheses automatically. In addition, You can request a new feature to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/suggest) and post the link here.

Comment: I don't understand, what does this option do? I found [a description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/141964/visual-studio-2019-c-intellisense-not- selecting-su.html)
Whether I turn it on or not, I can complete the function's name by typing part of the member function's name and then pressing ( directly, so this option has no effect on this, I'm visual studio 2022

Comment: Also, you're telling me that the functionality to parse macros and complete correctly doesn't exist, not that I don't know where it needs to be set, so this question is closed, thanks.

Comment: This option is used to automatically complete the full function name without using tab. So that you can enter shift+9. E.g.  `accu` and  shift+9-> accumulate().

Comment: But in my tests, even if I set this option to false, I still get the same result. E.g. accu and shift+9-> accumulate().